# Why is the AbstractRoutingDataSource.determineCurrentLookupKey() not called inside a @Transactional block?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I'm using Hibernate with Spring, relevant config:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="openSessionInViewInterceptor"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory"><ref bean="sessionFactory" /></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven  />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Answer (score 5):

Think about it...

1. Some code wants to obtain a `Connection` from a `DataSource`. Probably in order to start a transaction and run some SQL query
2. `AbstractRoutingDataSource` executes `determineCurrentLookupKey()` in order to find suitable `DataSource` from a set of available ones
3. Lookup key is used to obtain *current* `DataSource`. `AbstractRoutingDataSource` returns JDBC connections from that data source.
4. Connection is returned from `AbstractRoutingDataSource` as if it was a normal source.

Now you are asking why `determineCurrentLookupKey()` is not running within a transaction? First Spring would have to go to point 1. to fetch some database connection required to start a transaction. Look at the next point. See the problem? Smells like infinite recursion to me.

Simply put - `determineCurrentLookupKey()` can't run within a transaction because transaction needs a connection and the purpose of that method is to determine which `DataSource` to use to obtain a connection. See also: [*Chicken or the egg*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg).

Similarly, the engineers couldn't use a computer to design the first computer.

Comment: This is actually not correct. Hibernate does make a call to determine the DataSource using your defined AbstractRoutingSource. However, in the default Spring configuration, it will hold on to the connection until the session is closed (release_mode).

Comment: @arturnt: I am afraid I don't understand. Can you clarify a bit what session do you refer to and what do you mean by "default Spring configuration"? There is no session/transaction without connection that has to be first fetched from `AbstractRoutingSource`.

Comment: I added some configs above. The Spring's Transactional interceptor  will setup the Transaction, it will fetch a new connection from your DataSource if one is not already associated with your hibernate session. In the OSIV filter/interceptor a session will be associated with your entire request.